# How to send mouse events to the embedded flash player in qaxwidget

Tags: c++, qt, flash, activeqt

I have a QAxWidget which embeds a flash player and loads a swf. I don't want to use the widget, but instead i want to render the widget into a QImage, and then, use that image as a texture in my OpenSceneGraph node. Everything is ok, so far. But since there is no widget visible, i have to get the mouse move/press/release events from my osgView, calculate the corresponding position to my node, and send the events to the flash player to make actionscript mouse events work. The calculation part is tomorrow's problem. But up to now, i was not able to send any custom mouse event to the player. Does anyone have any opinion?

Here is the example code,

```
BFlashWidget::BFlashWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QAxWidget(parent)
{
    QSize imgSize(800,600);
    setMinimumSize(imgSize);

    setMouseTracking(true);

    mQtImg = QImage(imgSize, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);

    setControl(QString::fromUtf8("{d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000}"));
    dynamicCall("LoadMovie(long, string)", 0,
                QDir::currentPath() + "//deneme.swf");
    activateWindow();
}

BFlashWidget::~BFlashWidget()
{

}

QImage BFlashWidget::getImage()
{
    QPainter painter(&mQtImg);
    render(&painter);

    return mQtImg;
}

void BFlashWidget::simulateMouseMove(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QApplication::sendEvent(this, e);
    QApplication::processEvents();
}

void BFlashWidget::simulateMousePress(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QApplication::sendEvent(this, e);
    QApplication::processEvents();
}

void BFlashWidget::simulateMouseRelease(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QApplication::sendEvent(this, e);
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

player does nothing when i call those simulateMouseXXXXX methods

Comment: Show please how do you call simulateMouseXXXXX. Which QMouseEvent you pass as argument?

Comment: those QMouseEvent args come from QGLWidget which i embedded the osgViewer::CompositeViewer into. Practically from another widget with the same size.